# tf-neural network not working - pytorch does

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have created a tiny dataset where an exact linear relationship holds. The code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np

def gen_data(n, k):
    np.random.seed(5711)
    beta = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(k, 1))
    print("beta is:", beta)
    X = np.random.normal(size=(n, k))
    y = X.dot(beta).reshape(-1, 1)
    D = np.concatenate([X, y], axis=1)
    return D.astype(np.float32)
```

Now I have fitted a pyTorch neural network with SGD optimizer and MSE-loss and it converged approximately to the true values within 50 epochs and a learning rate of 1e-1

I tried to setup exactly the same model in tensorflow:

```
import keras.layers
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.models import Sequential
import tensorflow as tf

n = 10
k = 2
X = gen_data(n, k)
D_train, D_test = train_test_split(X, test_size=0.2)
X_train, y_train = D_train[:,:k], D_train[:,k:]
X_test, y_test = D_test[:,:k], D_test[:,k:]

model = Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(1)])
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-1), loss=tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error)
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=50)
```

When I call model.get_weights it shows substantial differences to the true values and the loss is still not even close to zero. I don't know why this model does not perform as well as the pytorch model. Even if you disregard the pytorch model, shoudln't the network converge to the true values in this tiny toy-dataset. What is my error in setting up the model?

EDIT: And here is my full pytorch code for comparison:

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset, Sampler, SequentialSampler, RandomSampler
from torch import nn
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

n = 10
k = 2
device =  "cpu"

class Daten(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df
        self.ycol = df.shape[1] - 1

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.df[index, :self.ycol], self.df[index, self.ycol:]

    def __len__(self):
        return self.df.shape[0]

def split_into(D, batch_size=64, **kwargs):
    D_train, D_test = train_test_split(D, **kwargs)
    df_train, df_test = Daten(D_train), Daten(D_test)
    dl_train, dl_test = DataLoader(df_train, batch_size=batch_size), DataLoader(df_test, batch_size=batch_size)
    return dl_train, dl_test

D = gen_data(n, k)
dl_train, dl_test = split_into(D, test_size=0.2)

class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(k, 1)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        ypred = self.linear(x)
        return ypred


model = NeuralNetwork().to(device)
print(model)
loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1e-1)

def train(dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer):
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    model.train()
    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
        X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)
        print(y.shape)

        # Compute prediction error
        pred = model(X)
        loss = loss_fn(pred, y)

        # Backpropagation
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        if batch % 100 == 0:
            loss, current = loss.item(), (batch + 1) * len(X)
            print(f"loss: {loss:>7f}  [{current:>5d}/{size:>5d}]")

epochs = 50
for t in range(epochs):
    print(f"Epoch {t + 1}\n-------------------------------")
    train(dl_train, model, loss_fn, optimizer)
print("Done!")
```

EDIT:

I increased epochs dramatically. After epochs=1000 we come close to the true values. Therefore my best guess for the discrepancy is that tf applies some non-optimal initialization?

Comment: Could be that the random initialisation is different between the two models? As well as setting the numpy seed, try also using `torch.manual_seed(...)` and `tf.random.set_seed(...)`. I think it's also worth trying out a smaller learning rate.

Comment: if you use `use_bias=False` in the Dense layer, it converges well.

Comment: Do you have an explanation for why bias=False is necessary to ensure convergence? I mean, predictions should be wrong if bias is set to zero.

Comment: I don't know if it's necessary to ensure convergence, but without that your model has more parameters than the function that generated the data. A model with too much capacity overfits. The degrees of freedom in the bias create noise that interferes with trying to learn the weights.

Comment: That can't be true. Three parameters can easily be estimated with n=8 observations with an ordinary regression model.

Comment: Can you share your torch code? I tried to replicate it, but it didn't converge either. For me it also does not converge very well without bias.

Comment: I just wanted to add that the model in torch now converges for me, I got something wrong before. Strange, will look into it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `lr` parameter for `SGD` is deprecated:

> WARNING:absl:`lr` is deprecated in Keras optimizer, please use `learning_rate` or use the legacy optimizer, e.g.,tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.SGD.

If I use

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-1), loss=tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error)
```

Then I get `loss: 7.0588e-05` (without bias: `loss: 2.0572e-08`).
With my simple torch model, I got `loss: 5.3355e-05` (without bias: `loss: 5.3071e-09`).

It's interesting that the bias plays a negative role here, I think the relation between X and y is too linear for the bias to get used, but the model tries it anyways. If you'd add the line

```
y += np.random.rand(*y.shape)*0.2
```

to the data creation, then the model with bias will perform better for torch and TF, as there is actual bias in the relation between X and y and the model can learn this.

Comment: That's interesting: Changing that single line solves the issue. Do you have any explanation what went wrong with the "lr=" version?

Comment: Yes, "deprecated" means this parameter does not exist anymore, and they warn you about it. They renamed it to `learning_rate`, probably to streamline a naming convention. If you call `SGD(lr=1-e1)`, the learning rate is never set to `1e-1`, but stays at the default value of `0.01` (=`1e-2`).

Comment: @P.Jo `~6e-5` is what I was getting without `use_bias=False`. I thought that's what you meant by not close to zero. So you're saying the issue is resolved when you stop using a deprecated parameter?

Comment: Considering that `y_train` ranges approximately from -1.85 to 0.34, an error in the range of `6e-5` is already 0.0027% of its range. Without bias it's even better, but I'd say both results are relatively close to zero. But yeah, the answer to this one was rather trivial and a good example to read warnings. @P.Jo, if you are satisfied with the solution, please mark this answer as accepted.